# 2 Dimensional QR(quick recognition ) encoding and decoding algorithm.

Tags: image-processing

I am working on 2- dimensional Quick Recognition(QR) code. can anyone suggest how to start with a method which involves steps like pre-processing, detecting three corners roughly, defining the three marked corners, detecting the fourth corner which has no mark and scanning of the code to create the size normalized and bi-level code image. I found the above steps in the web. I am confused what kind of image to take whether RGB or gray scale image.

Comment: I have only ever worked with 1d barcodes, but since there are no color features, I'd use a gray scale image.

Answer (score 1):

Recognizing a QR code is very non-trivial. The code itself is standardized but there are any number of heuristics that can be used to detect a code in image, each of which is going to perform differently in different environments (different amounts of shading, different amounts of perspective distortion, etc.)

zxing (http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) includes implementations in various languages (java, C++, others) that can be used off the shelf. Or you could read the code and look at the algorithms it uses for the various steps.

Comment: Thank you smparkes. But I just have to explain the steps involved in the decoding, i.e, for a normal process and that is in image processing using matlab tool. please suggest me a method to proceed with.

Comment: Sorry, but it's way too complicated too summarize. All I can suggest is reading the code.